# Linux-PAM not finding module

Tags: linux, pam

I have written my own custom Linux-pam module which will call facial recognition software (embedded Python3 in C) to recognise a users face and, subsequently , provide authentication.

I have ran into a problem, whenever I modify the /etc/pam.d/sudo file to use my pam_authnew.so module, it gives the error

`PAM module not found`

I have compiled the C file to a .so, I have loaded said file into /lib/x86_64/security (where all my other default pam modules reside)

Below are the /etc/pam.d/sudo , /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security and the /etc/var/auth.log files to aid in troubleshooting.

/etc/pam.d/sudo

```
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_rea$
#@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

/etc/var/auth.log

```
Feb 20 14:11:58 berns-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cw0xxx sudo: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_authnew.so): /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_authnew.so: undefined symbol: Py_Initialize
Feb 20 14:11:58 berns-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cw0xxx sudo: PAM adding faulty module: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_authnew.so
Feb 20 14:11:58 berns-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cw0xxx sudo:    berns : PAM authentication error: Module is unknown ; TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/berns ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt update
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept troubleshooting and discovered I never linked with

`-lpython3.6m`

So the Python libraries were NOT included in the .so file.

Comment: Please would you write up what Python libraries you are using.
I've been looking round and getting quite confused as what to use.
Is your module open source and have a github/lab link?

Comment: Hey @jradxl , the project was conducted as a college assignment at the time. It was a year ago now and to be honest, I wouldn't advocate it was conducted with best conventions in mind (python , c , Linux etc). I can however host it (some time soon) on github and I can share the link here. If memory serves me correct however,  it was indeed pure C/Python and manual manipulation of the Linux PAM

Comment: Hi @Pythoncrypt. Did you mean to add a Link?

Comment: Hey , sorry yes I did. The PAM directory and code directory of the project are in the link below, bear in mind this was many moons ago and a college submission so its not exactly brilliant lol ! Hopefully its some use :) https://github.com/PbernsY/PythonPam